# Androidx Kotlin using Gson, needing to created a nested GSON data class

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I've got an android app using kotlin, and I'm also using the gson google library.  What I'm trying to do is create a nested data class to match the json object I'm getting back.
JSON :

```
{
  "results":{
    "userid": "575",
    "email" : "joe@joe"
   },
   "errors": {"errormessage":"no errors found"}
}
```

I am creating a kotlin data class using GSON but I am not sure how to handle the nested portions so that the GSON object would match the json above
Below is what I think would work.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: @MartinZeitler that only parses to Java Objects

Comment: paste the java object in your code, then right click convert to kotlin

Comment: I would if it worked @LenaBru but it gave me a blank screen with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need all data being in same data class, you need first flatten the json using utilities like `json-flattener` which is available in following link:
The author has described how to use the library.

[Json-Flattener](https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener)

This utility will convert you hierarchical json object to flat format like:

```
{
    "results.userid": "575",
    "results.email": "joe@joe",
    "errors.errormessage": "no errors found"
}
```

Then you can deserialize it to the data class model like:

```
data class Response(
    @SerializedName("results.userid") val userId: String?,
    @SerializedName("results.email") val email: String?,
    @SerializedName("errors.errormessage") val errorMessage: String?
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data class Response( @SerializedName("results") val results: Results? = null, @SerializedName("errors") val errors: Errors? = null)

data class Results(@SerializedName("userid") val userId: String, @SerializedName("email") val email:String)

data class Errors(@SerializedName("errormessage") val errorMessage:String)
```

Comment: becuase of the requirements I would need them all in the same data class